# Are there any programs or drivers that can accelerate encryption using gpu/igp?

Tags: linux, encryption, gpgpu, opencl

Does anybody know of any linux tool that offloads- preferably in a transparent fashion- encryption to gpu?.
I'd like to buy an amd e350 apu for my nas and it would be great if i could boost otfe encryption rate using the gpu ( think about it, it would be like intel's hardware aes acceleration only this would be available for a lot of other algorithms aswell not necessarily for encryption but math operations in general).

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how useful or ready for prime time this is (looks like it isn't ready for serious use yet) but I found [KGPU](http://code.google.com/p/kgpu/) interesting.  According to [this Slashdot article](http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/11/05/06/1940220/writing-linux-kernel-functions-in-cuda-with-kgpu) it was used to speed up AES operations for filesystem crypto.  Again I currently have no idea how to use it.

Comment: it seems to be more like a framework to be used by programmers

Comment: check sisoftware.net for the e350 benchmarks and you will see that truecrypt accelerated using gpgpu has more than 3 times the throughput. So it looks pretty darn useful to me. At this rate amd would pwn intel on the  low cost market. And i'm willing to bet that even for mainstream productivity amd would become a favorite sice they ussualy have stronger gpus than intel